# How to set or select postgres' current_settings with peewee?

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I have a postgres database that I want to query with peewee in python. If I connect to the database directly (psql or pgadmin) I can do something like

```
set my.setting='test'
```

or

```
select current_setting('my.setting')
```

How can I do this with peewee? The model I have contains only the tables I have in my database.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute raw SQL using the `Database` method [`execute_sql(),`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.execute_sql) example:

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase("test")
db.execute_sql("set my.setting to 'test'")
cur = db.execute_sql("show my.setting")
print(cur.fetchone()[0])
```